Concatenate cells based off highest numerical value
I have a fairly large worksheet (around 6800 rows) of site access data that needs to be compiled in a specific way. I will try to explain this as best I can below. In summary, I need help with a concatenate formula that will concatenate rows based off the value in column B.
Link to sample workbook
Column A, "Site ID", lists the unique site identifier.
Column B, "Access Order", this lists the progression of access requirement. This can range from 1-7
Column C, "Access Type", This lists the type of access point they will face
Column D, "Code", This is the code or notes for that point of access
Column E, "Key", This identifies the key type if applicable
Column F, "Concate Access & Code", Concatenates column C & D
Column G, "Concat All", This Would concatenate the data for each point of access based off of how many point of access their are (Column B). So if the highest number listed for a site is 5, it would concatenate the all 5 points of access for that specific site.



Site ID
Access_Order
Access Type
Code
Key Type
Concat Access
Concat All for site




222722
1
Compound and cabinets
1234

Access Order - 1Compound and cabinets - Code: 1234



223301
1
Compound Gate
4567
Key Type - Combo
Access Order - 1Key Type - ComboCompound Gate - Code: 4567



223301
2
Shelter Door
55-a
Key Type - Key
Access Order - 2Key Type - KeyShelter Door - Code: 55-a
Access Order - 1Key Type - ComboCompound Gate - Code: 4567Access Order - 2Key Type - KeyShelter Door - Code: 55-a


223302
1
Compound Gate
1234
Key Type - Combo
Access Order - 1Key Type - ComboCompound Gate - Code: 1234



223302
2
Shelter Door
55-a
Keybox/Lockbox Location - Magnetic key box under HVAC unitKey Type - Key
Access Order - 2Keybox/Lockbox Location - Magnetic key box under HVAC unitKey Type - KeyShelter Door - Code: 55-a
Access Order - 1Key Type - ComboCompound Gate - Code: 1234Access Order - 2Keybox/Lockbox Location - Magnetic key box under HVAC unitKey Type - KeyShelter Door - Code: 55-a


223303
1
Compound Gate
1234
Key Type - Combo
Access Order - 1Key Type - ComboCompound Gate - Code: 1234



223303
2
AC Meter Compound Gate
55a
Key Type - Key
Access Order - 2Key Type - KeyAC Meter Compound Gate - Code: 55a



223303
3
Shelter Door
55a
Keybox/Lockbox Location - Shelter key is located in a magnetic key box under one of the HVAC units.Key Type - Key
Access Order - 3Keybox/Lockbox Location - Shelter key is located in a magnetic key box under one of the HVAC units.Key Type - KeyShelter Door - Code: 55a
Access Order - 1Key Type - ComboCompound Gate - Code: 1234Access Order - 2Key Type - KeyAC Meter Compound Gate - Code: 55aAccess Order - 3Keybox/Lockbox Location - Shelter key is located in a magnetic key box under one of the HVAC units.Key Type - KeyShelter Door - Code: 55a


223304
1
compound gate
1234
Key Type - combo
Access Order - 1Key Type - combocompound gate - Code: 1234



223304
2
shelter door
55A
Key Type - key
Access Order - 2Key Type - keyshelter door - Code: 55A



223304
3
Vendor access
located under HVAC unit with Shelter Key
Key Type - Magnetic Lock box
Access Order - 3Key Type - Magnetic Lock boxVendor access - Code: located under HVAC unit with Shelter Key
Access Order - 1Key Type - combocompound gate - Code: 1234Access Order - 2Key Type - keyshelter door - Code: 55AAccess Order - 3Key Type - Magnetic Lock boxVendor access - Code: located under HVAC unit with Shelter Key


223305
1
Compound Gate
8722
Key Type - Combo
Access Order - 1Key Type - ComboCompound Gate - Code: 8722



223305
2
Shelter Door
5A-2
Keybox/Lockbox Location - Shelter key is located in a magnetic key box under one of the HVAC units.Key Type - Key
Access Order - 2Keybox/Lockbox Location - Shelter key is located in a magnetic key box under one of the HVAC units.Key Type - KeyShelter Door - Code: 5A-2
Access Order - 1Key Type - ComboCompound Gate - Code: 8722Access Order - 2Keybox/Lockbox Location - Shelter key is located in a magnetic key box under one of the HVAC units.Key Type - KeyShelter Door - Code: 5A-2




If you got Excel365 probably you may benefit from MAXIFS combined with FILTER to get your desired output

@FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns, would you be posting an answer? Otherwise, I'll give it a shot.

With tables we can use column names among other benefits; so, if using table is feasible for your task,
For the Concate Access & Code column - clear all the existing cells in the column and enter this in the first cell. As a calculated column it will be filled automatically, also for new rows.
=LET(
    newline, CHAR(10),
    CONCAT(
        IF(
            ISBLANK([@[Access_Order]]),
            "",
            "Access Order - " & [@[Access_Order]] & newline
        ),
        IF(ISBLANK([@[Key Type]]), "", [@[Key Type]] & newline),
        IF(ISBLANK([@[Access Type]]), "", [@[Access Type]] & " - "),
        IF(ISBLANK([@Code]), "", "Code: " & [@Code])
    )
)

For the Concat All column (as Foxfire And Burns And Burns suggested):
=LET(
    newline, CHAR(10),
    max_order, MAXIFS([Access_Order], [Site ID], [@[Site ID]]),
    IF(
        (max_order > 1) * ([@[Access_Order]] = max_order),
        TEXTJOIN(
            REPT(newline, 2),
            ,
            FILTER([Concat Access], [Site ID] = [@[Site ID]])
        ),
        ""
    )
)



Using ranges instead of tables, dynamic (spill array)
For the Concate Access & Code column - clear all the existing cells in the column and enter this in the first cell. rows.
=LET(
    comment_1, "Instead the whole col (f.ex. G:G), set to a suitable max",
    last_data_cell, $G$8000,
    data, $A$2:INDEX($G$2:last_data_cell, COUNTA($A$2:$A$8000)),
    site_id, INDEX(data, , 1),
    access_order, INDEX(data, , 2),
    access_type, INDEX(data, , 3),
    code, INDEX(data, , 4),
    key_type, INDEX(data, , 5),
    newline, CHAR(10),
    CONCATENATE(
        IF(ISBLANK(site_id), "", "Access Order - " & site_id & newline),
        IF(ISBLANK(key_type), "", key_type & newline),
        IF(ISBLANK(access_type), "", access_type & " - "),
        IF(ISBLANK(code), "", "Code: " & code)
    )
)

For the Concat All column, fill only in the first cell, clearing the ones below:
=LET(
    comment_1, "Instead the whole col (f.ex. G:G), set to a suitable max",
    last_data_cell, $G$8000,
    data, $A$2:INDEX($G$2:last_data_cell, COUNTA($A$2:$A$8000)),
    site_id, INDEX(data, , 1),
    access_order, INDEX(data, , 2),
    contact_access, INDEX(data, , 6),
    newline, CHAR(10),
    MAP(
        SEQUENCE(ROWS(data)),
        LAMBDA(r,
            IF(
                (INDEX(access_order, r) > 1) *
                    (
                        INDEX(access_order, r) =
                            MAXIFS(access_order, site_id, INDEX(site_id, r))
                    ),
                TEXTJOIN(
                    REPT(newline, 2),
                    ,
                    FILTER(contact_access, site_id = INDEX(site_id, r))
                ),
                ""
            )
        )
    )
)



This is the formula in cell F2 (in the example, place in G2 for your table) and drag down:
=LET(uni,ROWS(FILTER(A$2:D$14,A2=A$2:A$14)),
ta,DROP(TEXTSPLIT(REPT(" Access_Order - "&"|",uni),,"|"),-1),
tb,DROP(TEXTSPLIT(REPT(" "&"|",uni),,"|"),-1),
tc,DROP(TEXTSPLIT(REPT(" Code: "&"|",uni),,"|"),-1),
td,DROP(TEXTSPLIT(REPT(CHAR(10)&CHAR(10)&"|",uni),,"|"),-1),
IF(AND(B2=uni,uni<>1),CONCAT(ta&B2:OFFSET(B2,-uni+1,0)&tb&E2:OFFSET(E2,-uni+1,0)&tb&C2:OFFSET(C2,-uni+1,0)&tc&D2:OFFSET(D2,-uni+1,0)&td),""))


